# How can I merge / Sum Rows that have the same Value in a given column. Then Histogram. R studio

Tags: r, database, sum, histogram, rows

I am using R studio.

I Have filtered some data to create a new tibble that has only 2 variables.

```
df1 <- df %>% dplyr::select(Species, Weight)
```

Which gives me some sample data as so

```
   Species  Weight
1    Dog      7
2    Cat      2
3    Dog      5
4    Dog      4
.     .       .
.     .       .
245  Cat      3
246  Dog      9
247  Cat      2
```

This is an example of data as the data I am using actually contains 25 species of fish.
How can I add the weight of every species together so we just have one species on each row like this:

```
   Species  Weight
1    Dog      734
2    Cat      257
```

As I would then like to plot the species against the total weight in a histogram.

Any help with the histogram code would also be very appreciated!

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'Species' and then do the `sum` on the 'Weight' and then plot the bars with `geom_col` from `ggplot2`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      group_by(Species) %>%
      summarise(Weight = log(sum(Weight))) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Weight)) + 
              geom_col()
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
aggregate(Weight ~ Species, df, sum)
```

If we need a barplot, then use

```
barplot(rowsum(df$Weight, df$Species)[,1])
```

If we need a `log`, then wrap with `log`

```
barplot(log(rowsum(df$Weight, df$Species))[,1])
```

#### data

```
df  <- structure(list(Species = c("Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Dog", "Cat", 
"Dog", "Cat"), Weight = c(7L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "245", "246", "247"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply akrun! I forgot to mention that I must plot this using a log scale as the figure margins are too hard. How would I do this? Thank you for all your help. Im very new to this

Comment: @T.Omalley updaed the post with `log`

Comment: Hello Akun, The first part of the code works great, However the part that states ```%>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Weight)) + 
              geom_col()``` gives me an error code ```Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "%>%"
>   ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Weight)) + 
+   geom_col()
Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.```

Comment: @T.Omalley not clear about your comment.   It is from `ggplot2`.  It is working fine for me

Comment: @T.Omalley updated with the data I used.  It is working for that

Comment: @T.Omalley  your error shows that data is not data.frame.  Not clear about the structure of your data

Comment: Ive now used ggplot and have a histogram what I need. I used this ```df %>%
group_by(Species) %>% summarise(Weight = (sum(Weight)))

p5 = ggplot(data = df, aes(x = weight)) +
  geom_histogram(mapping = aes(colour = Species), binwidth=60) + scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log2')
p5``` thank you so much for your help tho